# Reduce margin chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters, titlesec

I'm stuck here, I can't reduce the margin before and after my chapter command,
I've tried the command titlespacing but nothing happened.

How to reduced this space??

code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0}{1pt}{2pt}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}

    \section{Les Escherichia coli pathogènes}
    \subsection{Caractères généraux}
        Escherichia coli (E.coli) est un bacille à
\end{document}
```

*The spaces I want to reduce are the space before and after the title.*

Result :
[image: Resultat du chapitre]

Thank a lot in advance <3 <3 <3

Ju

Comment: As you don't provide any code, it is a bit hard for us to help, sorry.

Comment: Indeed, it'll be complex...
Question edited !

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `utf8x` use just `utf8`.

Comment: Is fncychap and titlesec even compatible? Probably to some extend. You might want to be a bit more explicit in your question as to exactly which spacings to want to control

Comment: For utf8, thanks, it's corrected !
For fncycchap, I've tried to comment this line to see, and no effect :/

Comment: I updated the answer as asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two lengths to control the spacing: one between the top of the page and the chapter heading
(`\beforechapter`) and one between the chapter heading and the text below (`\afterchapter`)

Since you are using `fncychap` to lay out the chapter heading, `titleec` is irrelevant here.

**UPDATE**

Now Including the table of contents and bibliography page as asked.

[image: x]
[image: y]
[image: z]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{showframe} % show margins
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}


%% *********************************************** added
\newlength{\beforechapter}
\newlength{\afterchapter}

\setlength{\beforechapter}{-3\baselineskip} % substract some space before the chapter title <<<<<<
\setlength{\afterchapter}{2\baselineskip} % add space after chapter title   <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settoheight{\myhi}{\CTV\FmTi{Test}}
    \setlength{\py}{\baselineskip}
    \addtolength{\py}{\RW}
    \addtolength{\py}{\myhi}
    \setlength{\pyy}{\py}
    \addtolength{\pyy}{-1\RW}
    \vskip \beforechapter
    \raggedright
    \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space\CNoV\thechapter
    \hskip 3pt\mghrulefill{\RW}\rule[-1\pyy]{2\RW}{\py}\par\nobreak}


  \renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \addtolength{\pyy}{-4pt}
    \settoheight{\myhi}{\CTV\FmTi{#1}}
    \addtolength{\myhi}{\py}
    \addtolength{\myhi}{-1\RW}
    \vskip -1\pyy
    \rule{2\RW}{\myhi}\mghrulefill{\RW}\hskip 2pt
    \raggedleft\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip \afterchapter
}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    \vskip \beforechapter
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \DOTIS{#1}
        \vskip -40\p@
        \vskip \afterchapter}
    }


\makeatother
%% *********************************************** added

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \section{Les Escherichia coli pathogènes}
    \subsection{Caractères généraux}
    Escherichia coli (E.coli) est un bacille à
    
    \chapter{Method}
    Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} 
    book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the 
    Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are
    \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 
    

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{latexcompanion} 
    Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin. 
    \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}. 
    Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
    
    \bibitem{einstein} 
    Albert Einstein. 
    \textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
    [\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
    Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.
    
    \bibitem{knuthwebsite} 
    Knuth: Computers and Typesetting,
    \\\texttt{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just tried and it's returning two error (the same one) :

- LaTeX Error: Command \DOCH undefined.
- LaTeX Error: Command \DOTI undefined.

Comment: Forget it, it's worked perfectly, I've just comment the bad line !!
Thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: Thank you Simon Dispa !! But I still have a problem, this solution is working for each chapter, except for the table of content and the bibliography... which is still the same.

Any idea to solve this ?

Thanks !!

Comment: @Juju Please see the updated answer.

Comment: It's working perfectly !!! Thank you a lot !!